# autofac mvc areas in separate projects

Tags: autofac, areas

I've separated my MVC4 app into areas BUT using separate projects In each module project (area) I have a module to register the controllers

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            builder.RegisterControllers(assembly);
            builder.RegisterModelBinders(assembly);
            builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
        }
```

I have a controller

```
public class SomeController : Controller {
        public SomeController (IDependency dependency){}
 }
```

and in the main project global I have this:

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyModules();
```

Then when I run this I get this error:

```
No parameterless constructor provided.
```

It seems that the registration did not happen. The areas projects are NOT referenced in the main project

How can I register them?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely (without seeing how your project is set up and being initialized, other than the tiny code snippet provided in the question) this is a problem with ASP.NET being unable to properly locate the type to resolve.

**Make sure you've got your plugin assemblies registered with the BuildManager.**

[This blog article should help you get where you need to go.](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2013/01/21/putting-controllers-in-plugin-assemblies-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx)